# How to avoid text coloring when using tracing-appender?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

When I write logs to a file with [tracing-appender](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-appender), I get output with terminal color artifacts which do not render when viewing them as a text file:

```
[2mOct 02 23:44:57.484[0m [34mDEBUG[0m
```

Is there a way to drop these artifacts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`with_ansi()`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.2.24/tracing_subscriber/fmt/struct.Layer.html#method.with_ansi) option is on by default when using `tracing_subcriber::fmt()`. Set it to `false` by using the builder method to declare your subscriber:

```rust
let (non_blocking, _guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(TestWriter);

tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_writer(non_blocking)
    .with_ansi(false) // <------ this
    .init();
```

You can have multiple subscribers if you want to inject color on the terminal but not in the file.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, you can use like this if you are using `axum` with `tracing_subscriber`:

```rust
tracing_subscriber::registry()
  .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().with_ansi(false))
  .init();
```